# random `/undefined ` addition to request link from .env files

Tags: javascript, api, url, axios

I am building a react app and i have hooked it up to my API. I was trying to see if the API could communicate with the app and they do but there is a problem. I want to use my .env variables to connect to my api but when im trying to make a request a random `/undefined` shows up at the link im trying to reach. Example: 

what i want the app to request : `PATCH https://myapi.com/1/1/false` 
the link the app actually uses : `PATCH https://myapi.com/undefined/1/1/false`
I figured out it was the .env file's fault because when i changed my value on the codes app : 

from: `const url = process.env.CONNECTION_URL` 
to : `const url = "https://myapi.com"` 

it works like a charm. Is there anything i can do to remove the `/undefined` from the link ?

Comment: How do you supply the `.env` variables to the react app? Also please be aware that custom `.env` varables must be prefixed with `REACT_APP_` https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env all other variables will be ignored.

Comment: @evolutionxbox with a .env file located in the app's folder and using the dotenv package.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thx man the link you gave me saved me. Didnt know of that detail.

Comment: @andriotisnikos1 you should remove the `dotenv` package as React comes with a variant of it